# Is there a way to refactor this AND and XOR logical branch?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

I have 2 user IDs and I would like to do different but very similar logic if I have only one or both. Is there a way to consolidate this code, as right now it looks ugly.

```js
function getUserPermission(primaryId, secondaryId, role) {
  let permission = userInfo.permissionList.filter( permission => {

    //logical AND
    if(primaryId && secondaryId){
      // have both IDs, use both IDs
      (permission.primaryId === primaryId && permission.secondaryId === secondaryId) && permission.role === role
    } 

    //logical XOR
    else if((primaryId && !secondaryId) || (!primaryId && secondaryId)) {
      // have only 1 ID, use 1 ID 
      (permission.primaryId === primaryId || permission.secondaryId === secondaryId) && permission.role === role
    }

  })[0]

  return permission
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it seems like this logic doesn't handle when both ids are invalid. You'll want to handle that somehow (looks like both the other answers so far include something along those lines).

Next, since you're only returning the first matching permission, I would suggest using a solution that doesn't keep looping once you've found that first match. In that respect, `Array.find()` is far better than `Array.filter()` for this use case.

If I were to put the other answers together, it would be something like this:

```
function getUserPermission(primaryId, secondaryId, role) {
  if (!primaryId && !secondaryId) return null // at least one must be populated, why loop at all?
  return userInfo.permissionList.find(permission => 
    permission.role === role
      && (!primaryId || primaryId === permission.primaryId) // if primary is populated, it needs to match
      && (!secondaryId || secondaryId === permission.secondaryId) // if secondary is populated, it needs to match
  );
}
```

...but that doesn't handle the case where a perfectly valid ID happens to be 0. That could depend on your data, though. Perhaps you're always using string-based IDs, for example. It also checks for valid ids on every loop (something you may or may not be perfectly comfortable with)

With those potential issues in mind, I made some assumptions about your data/types and threw a more unorthodox approach together in an attempt to solve them:

```
const getUserPermission = (primaryId = -1, secondaryId = -1, role = '') => {
  if (primaryId < 0 && secondaryId < 0) return null

  const conditions = [ p => p.role === role ]
    .concat(primaryId >= 0 ? [ p => p.primaryId === primaryId ] : [])
    .concat(secondaryId >= 0 ? [ p => p.secondaryId === secondaryId ] : [])

  return userInfo.permissionList.find(p => conditions.every(fn => fn(p)))
}
```

...this last one makes an array of functions, `conditions`, to check each permission against. The first one to match every condition should be returned (in theory, at least - I didn't test it)

Comment: thanks for the thorough explanation. The data is in string format (with 6 characters) so your alternate solution isn't necessary. But kudos for thinking outside the box!

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
if(!primaryId && !secondaryId) {
  throw Error("No ID was provided");
}
let permission = userInfo.permissionList.filter(p => p.role === role);
if(primaryId) {
  permission = permission.filter(p => p.primaryId === primaryId);
}
if(secondaryId) {
  permission = permission.filter(p => p.secondaryId === secondaryId);
}
return permission[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getUserPermission(primaryId, secondaryId, role) {
  return userInfo.permissionList.find(permission => 
    permission.role === role
      && (!!primaryId || !!secondaryId)// at least one is populated
      && (!primaryId || primaryId === permission.primaryId)// if primary is populated, it needs to match
      && (!secondaryId || secondaryId === permission.secondaryId)// if secondary is populated, it needs to match
    );
}
```

This is slightly different from your code in that if there is no match, it returns null, whereas yours throws an exception. If you mean to throw, you can always put the result in a variable and check for null.

Answer (score 0):

What about this refactoring :

```
function getUserPermission(primaryId = undefined,secondaryId = undefined,role) {

  primaryId === undefined && secondaryId === undefined && throw new Error("Ids are required");

  const userPermission = userInfo.permissionList
    .filter((permission) => role && permission.role === role)
    .filter((permission) => primaryId && permission.primaryId === primaryId)
    .filter(
      (permission) => secondaryId && permission.secondaryId === secondaryId
    );

  return userPermission[0];
}
```